# Restore Graph Editor F-Curve Filter Location

Tags: graph-editor, fcurves

Moving to 2.8 I realized that the search bar for F-curve filter is now located inside an extra menu as shown below:

[image]

This is very counter-productive as animating requires you to filter out many curves several times. This makes it extra painful to change the filter. Is there a way to restore it's position to be outside on the bottom bar like in 2.78?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter entry is also always available at the top of the channel list in any of the animation editors.

This is the same filter property that is shown in the popup menu.

[image: filter entry location]

Comment: OOF I didnt see it. That's a bit awkward of a location but miles better. Thanks.